# Furutsu-Novikov Formula Generalisation

Tags: statistical-mechanics, stochastic-processes, functional-derivatives

The Furutsu-Novikov formula gives the expectation value of a zero mean Gaussian process $z(t)$ and a functional of that process $R[z]$:
$$\langle{z(t') R[z]}\rangle = \int^{t}_0 \mathrm{d}s K_2(t',s) \left\langle{\frac{\delta R[z]}{\delta z(s)}}\right\rangle,$$
where $K_2(t,s)$ is the 2-point second cumulant of the process. Can one use this formula recursively to derive
$$\langle{z(t')z(t') R[z]}\rangle =  K_2(t',t') \langle R[z]\rangle+\int^{t}_0 \mathrm{d}s_1 K_2(t',s_1)\int^{t}_0 \mathrm{d}s_2 K_2(t',s_2) \left\langle{\frac{\delta^2 R[z]}{\delta z(s_1)\delta z(s_2)}}\right\rangle?$$
Will it work for $0<t'\le t$?

Comment: I suggest to check out the books on random oscillations by Gitterman. One is on the pendulum and the other is on the simple harmonic oscillator. He summarizes tons of correlation splitting problems like this one